# Can you identify this battery connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to identify this battery connector. The part on the battery has a 3.1mm height, and 2.34mm width. The pitch is around .8mm give or take .3mm. The mating connector is 3.83mm wide and 2.7mm tall. It has JST written on the receptacle.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Typing 'jst battery connector' into google yields many many results including digikey product links. Are you posting this question because you've already done this and didn't find an exact match for your dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes JST is the manufacture. I found that only Digikey had a good selection. If you need the connector on the battery cable end. The pins are sold separately. Order two times what you need! The are "full Cycle" type crimp pins. You must copy or reproduce the original crimp profile for current load, contact resistance and shell latching integrity. Keep the original pins as a reference sample.

FIY It looks like you have one or more bad solder joint on the PCB connector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes JST is the manufacture. I found that only Digikey had a good selection. If you need the connector on the battery cable end. The pins are sold separately. Order two times what you need! The are "full Cycle" type crimp pins. You must copy or reproduce the original crimp profile for current load, contact resistance and shell latching integrity. Keep the original pins as a reference sample.

Comment: Please remove this answer since it's posted twice. Did you try to edit it to add your FYI comment?